# Why my input on blur function only work in first page?

Tags: php, codeigniter, pagination

I'm developing the web using PHP and CI frameworks. I have data that is shown in the table and some fields are editable. The table shows using pagination and the default show entries is 10 entries data. I have on blur function when editing the field value, but this function only works on the first page. It doesn't work on the second page or more. Could you give me clues on how to fix this? Here is my code.

```js
$('input.AmountInput').on('blur', function() {
  let value = this.value.replace(/,/g, '');
  alert(value);

  if (value == '')
  {
    value = 0;
  }

  if (!$.isNumeric(value))
  {
    value = 0;
  }

  this.value = parseFloat(value).toLocaleString('en-US', {
    style: 'decimal',
    maximumFractionDigits: 2,
    minimumFractionDigits: 2
  });
  hitungTotalAmount();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" class="AmountInput">
```

After inputting the field, it automatically changes the format number. But when I input the field on the second page, it doesn't work. Please help me to fix this. Thank you

Comment: just to be sure, this script fires again on the new page?

Comment: @GijsBeijer yes, I need this script works on all pages but right now it only works in the first page

Comment: _But when I input the field in the second page_ So what does this second page look like? Does it include this javascript code?

Comment: @RiggsFolly I have 16 entries that show in table which show only 10 entries. It means the table has 2 page, right? Let say I have "Amount" field. When I edit the Amount value in the first page, my on blur works but in the second page it doesn't work at all.

Comment: @TiaraDwiDikiyanti pls read my comment again carefully: `$(...).controlSidebar` error is nowhere related to this code. so seems like another jquery code is giving an error which makes the above code stop as well.